Calculating angle of 3D vector.
I am trying to make a program to calculate the ground track of a satellite around the Earth. I have got stuck trying to find the angle of the ground track relative to the equatorial plane.

In the above diagram, angle $a$ is the inclination of the orbit relative to the equator, and this angle is a constant. Angle $b$ is the angle indicating the latitude of the point the satellite is above at any given time. What I am trying to calculate is the angle $c$ of the satellite's instantaneous tangential velocity vector relative to the equatorial plane.
When the satellite is passing over the equator, $b=0$ and $c=a$. When the satellite ground track reaches its maximum latitude, $b=a$ and $c=0$. That much is easy, but the calculating c at lower latitudes stumped me.
I tried some reasonable guesses such as $$c = a \cos \left(\frac{b}{a} \frac {\pi}{2} \right) $$  and $$c = \sqrt{a^2 -b^2} $$ but neither is an exact solution except at the endpoints.
I would like to know what the exact analytical solution for angle $c$ is if that is possible.
In the chart below, with the inclination of the orbit plotted on the $x$-axis, the green curve is the cosine-based formula, the blue curve is the square root formula, and the red curve is the first equation suggested by pauca in the comments.

=================================================
EDIT: I have updated the chart to correct an error in the original data points and to add the orange curve, which is the latest equation $$\cos(c) = \frac{\cos(a)}{\cos(b)}$$ provided by pauca, and I am pleased to announce that it appears to be an exact fit to the data points extracted from the 3D model (black crosses).
=================================================
For clarity, the purple vector in the GeoGebra image is the instantaneous tangential velocity, the red vector is the component of the tangential velocity that is parallel to the equatorial plane, and both red and blue components lie in a plane that is tangential to the idealised sphere, at the point where the ground track is at that instant.
If it helps, the interactive 3D Geogebra construction is here.

You cannot compute the sign of $c$ from $a$ and $b$: it's evident that there are two points on the orbit with the same value of $b$ but opposite values of $c$.

Anyway, I think a possible result is as follows: $$|\sin c|=\sqrt{\cos^2b\sin^2a-\sin^2b\cos^2a}=\sqrt{\sin(a+b)\sin(a-b)}$$

@Intelligentipauca Yes, there are two solutions that only differ in sign, depending on whether or not the satellite is ascending or descending and they correspond to the two roots of the square root.  Unfortunately your result is not an exact solution. See the chart I added to my post.

Your angle $c$ in the GeoGebra construction is not the one defined above, because the red vector $AJ$ is not the projection of $AH$ onto the plane through $A$ parallel to the equator. Correct this and you'll see my formula is fine.

Using your edited definition of $c$ (i.e. $c$ is the angle between the instantaneous velocity and a line parallel to the equator and perpendicular to the position vector $OA$) I got this result: $$\cos c={\cos a\over\cos b}.$$ I checked with your GeoGebra file and it works.

@Intelligentipauca Your latest equation appears to be spot on. Sterling work! I have updated the chart in my question to reflect this.

The formula $\cos(c) = \cos(a)/\cos(b)$ is derivable from Clairaut's formula, remembering that in the conventional Clairaut's formula the direction angle is relative to a line of longitude rather than a line of latitude.

@Intelligentipauca You were right that the original 3D construction was a bit awkward, so I I have rewritten it, so that the b angle can be entered directly rather than by trial and error.
